# Apply custom function to cells of selected columns of a data frame in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
+---+-----------+-----------+
| id|   address1|   address2|
+---+-----------+-----------+
|  1|address 1.1|address 1.2|
|  2|address 2.1|address 2.2|
+---+-----------+-----------+
```

I would like to apply a custom function directly to the strings in the *address1* and *address2* columns, for example:

```
def example(string1, string2):
    name_1 = string1.lower().split(' ')
    name_2 = string2.lower().split(' ')
    intersection_count = len(set(name_1) & set(name_2))

    return intersection_count
```

I want to store the result in a new column, so that my final data frame would look like:

```
+---+-----------+-----------+------+
| id|   address1|   address2|result|
+---+-----------+-----------+------+
|  1|address 1.1|address 1.2|     2|
|  2|address 2.1|address 2.2|     7|
+---+-----------+-----------+------+
```

I've tried to execute it in a way I once applied a built-in function to the whole column, but I got an error:

```
>>> df.withColumn('result', example(df.address1, df.address2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in example
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

What am I doing wrong and how I can apply a custom function to strings in selected columns?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use udf (user defined function) in spark

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
example_udf = udf(example, LongType())
df.withColumn('result', example_udf(df.address1, df.address2))
```

Comment: Thanks! I just have one more question: why are we using LongType() specifically? Does it have something to do with the data type return by a given function?

Comment: Yes, it should be the return type by the given function

Comment: Can I pass additional arguments, which do not come from the data frame? For example, if I wanted to define example as:

    def example(source_name1, source_name2, string1, string2):
        return json.dumps({source_name1: string1, source_name2: string2})

Comment: Yes, you can pass additional arguments

Comment: But when I tried to pass a string I got: pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'string1' given input columns

Comment: That's because udf expect columns, but you can convert those values as columns with lit function. Eg: lit("abcd").as("dummy_col") will create a column named dummy_cal with values for all rows "abcd"

Answer (score 3):

Simply "decorate" your function with a required wrapper `udf` from PySpark:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf


@udf
def foo(...):
    ...

df.withColumn('result', foo(df['address1'], df['address2']))
```