# PySpark RDD: The number of columns doesn't match

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hash, rdd

I want to build a dataframe using pyspark with one of the column that is the result of a [SipHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SipHash) of two other columns of the dataset. To do so, I created a function that is called in `rdd.map()` function as follow:

```py
import siphash
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *

sqlContext = SQLContext( spark )

# Hashing function
def hash_two_columns( row ):
    # Transform row to a dict
    row_dict = row.asDict()
    # Concat col1 and col2
    concat_str = 'E'.join( [str(row_dict['col1']), str(row_dict['col2'])] )
    # Fill string with 0 to get 16 bytes (otherwise error is raised)
    sixteenBytes_str = concat_str.zfill(16)
    # Preserve concatenated value for testing (this can be removed later)
    row_dict["hashcols_str"] = sixteenBytes_str
    # Calculate siphash
    row_dict["hashcols_id"] = siphash.SipHash_2_4( sixteenBytes_str.encode('utf-8') ).hash()
    return Row( **row_dict )

# Create test dataframe
test_df = spark.createDataFrame([
         (1,"text1",58965,11111),
         (3,"text2",78652,888888),
         (4,"text3",78652,888888),              
    ], ("id","item","col1","col2"))

# Build the schema 
# Using this to avoid "ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined by the first 100 rows" when pyspark tries to deduct schema by itself
test_df_schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("item", StringType(), True),
    StructField("col1", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("col2", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("hashcols_str", StringType(), True),
    StructField("hashcols_id", LongType(), True)
])

# Create the final Dataframe
final_test_df = sqlContext \
     .createDataFrame(
          test_df.rdd.map(hash_two_columns).collect(), 
          test_df_schema) \
     .toDF()

final_test_df.show(truncate=False)
```

Although the schema definition matches the final dataframe structure, running this code fails with the following error:

> IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match. Old column names (6): id, item, col1, col2, hashcols_str, hashcols_id New column names (0): (java.lang.RuntimeException)

Does anyone have any idea of how to implement this correctly? Thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45367824/apply-custom-function-to-cells-of-selected-columns-of-a-data-frame-in-pyspark):

Update the function that way:

```py
def hash_two_columns( col1, col2 ):
    # Concat col1 and col2
    concat_str = 'E'.join( [col1, col2] )
    # Fill string with 0 to get 16 bytes (otherwise error is raised)
    sixteenBytes_str = concat_str.zfill(16)
    # Calculate siphash
    hashcols_id = siphash.SipHash_2_4( sixteenBytes_str.encode('utf-8') ).hash()
    return hashcols_id
```

Then, use UDF (user defined function) to add the new column to the dataframe using `withColumn` functionality.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

example_udf = udf( hash_two_columns, LongType() )

test_df = test_df \
    .withColumn( "hashcols_id", example_udf( test_df.col1, test_df.col2 ) )

test_df.show()
```